# Microsoft Graph Upload API: Intermittent 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to upload images to one drive and intermittently getting
`500 - Internal Server Error`.

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/drive/items/{rootFolderId}/{folderPath}/{fileName}:/content
```

Response:

```
{
   "statusCode":500,
   "error":{
      "code":"InternalServerError",
      "message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
      "innerError":{
         "request-id":"5f45d50e-6cd5-41c9-9c89-ca90d188e0eb",
         "date":"2018-05-24T10:37:44"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not [addressing your path properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems). The path must be surrounded by `:`:

```
:/filder/filename.ext:
```

It should look something like this:

```
/users/{userId}/drive/items/{rootFolderId}:/{folderPath}/{fileName}:/content
```

or

```
/users/{userId}/drive/items/{folderid}/{fileName}/content
```

Comment: Yes, tried that, still facing this issue intermittently.

Comment: How large is the image you're uploading?